# How can i release the camera<imutils.video.webcamvideostream.WebcamVideoStream instance at 0x7f2c40e75b00>

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv, tkinter

i use this code to start the camera

```
from imutils.video import Videostream
vs = VideoStream(0).start()
```

but when i try this

```
vs.stop()
```

the camera doesn't stop and the variable vs show this value :

```
<imutils.video.webcamvideostream.WebcamVideoStream instance at 0x7f2c40e75b00>
```

Comment: I would guess that you need to separate `vs` into two lines: `vs = VideoStream(0)` and `vs.start()`.

Comment: @Nae and how can i release the camera .can you guide me ?

Comment: I can't, I'm not familiar with the topic exactly.

Answer (score 4):

imutils actually uses cv2.VideoCapture() to initialize stream, but didn't release it in stop.

vs.stream.release() shall work.

I've created pull request in imutils github repo :)
https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/pull/81/files

Answer (score 4):

`vs.stream.release()` didn't work for me.

`vs.stream.stream.release()` worked perfectly.

Comment: For me when using it along with `openCV`the first one `vs.stream.release()` did it for me. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Imutils build using OpenCV, so we need to use release() to release the webcam. I have tried stop() earlier, then I realized and used release() and it is working fine for me.

```
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start() ## To launch the cam
vs.stream.release() # To release the camera
```

Comment: This solved it for me as well. It may appear to be a [longstanding documented bug](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/issues/35) in [this source](https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/blob/c12f15391fcc945d0d644b85194b8c044a392e0a/imutils/video/webcamvideostream.py#L42) not fully doing the cleanup, thus requiring this workaround.